# .htaccess redirecting issue in a codeigniter application

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a problem with codeigniter and the .htaccess, I have been looking for an answer here but I can't find it, so I would thank any help on this :-)

On my index.php, the first line is this one:

```
echo var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
die();
```

My .htaccess is this one:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error

# Set default charset
AddDefaultCharset utf-8

RewriteEngine On

# From non-www to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^paravegetarianos\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.paravegetarianos.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# General
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.+)\.(js|css|gif|png|jpg|jpeg|bmp|swf|txt|xml|htc|pdf|xls|doc|ico)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

And when I put on the browser to this url:

**www.paravegetarianos.loc/comunidad/jonaypelluz/albums/danna/ca_1**

it will redirect to:

**http://www.paravegetarianos.loc/danna**

and it will print:

```
string '/danna' (length=6)
```

and this is the line in the access.log:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Oct/2011:21:56:12 +0200] "GET /danna HTTP/1.1" 200 123
```

I suppose my rewriting rules are not working properly :-) Thanks!

Comment: What is it that you are expecting when you put `www.paravegetarianos.loc/comunidad/jonaypelluz/albums/danna/ca_1` into the browser?

Comment: You're probably not telling us the full story. With the index.php and .htaccess files as described here, in a clean and relatively standard web server configuration, the basic front controller works as expected and prints: string '/comunidad/jonaypelluz/albums/danna/ca_1' (length=40) as expected. You don't need the echo before var_dump. Nothing here is CodeIgniter-specific, so have you omitted something and do you have details about the web server configuration?

Comment: works in the same lcalhost with a simple php & the .htaccess I wrote before but it doesnt with codeigniter..

This is the vhost

`<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerAdmin ad@vgs.loc
 DocumentRoot "E:/workspace/paravegetarianos"
 ServerName paravegetarianos.loc
        ServerAlias *.paravegetarianos.loc
 <Directory "E:/workspace/paravegetarianos">
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
  AllowOverride All
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>`

I'd like to know what makes the url to redirect to /danna if it's htaccess related or something else I'm missing Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already said, i think you must look elsewhere than in the codes you gave because i can't see nothing wrong with it.

If you are using routing feature, check the custom routes settings in /config/routes.php.

Comment: I have checked it many times, the funny thing is, it works with `http://www.paravegetarianos.loc/comunidad/jonaypelluz/albums/danna-pelluz/ca_1`, but it doesn't with `http://www.paravegetarianos.loc/comunidad/jonaypelluz/albums/lopsum-ipsum-lorem-amet-sit-adet/ca_1e`. it seems to be random. I will try to find a solution, thanks for the answers :-)

Comment: I found the solution, and I feel a bit stupid :-), the browser and the app somehow was caching something there and making funny redirections. Thanks for the help! :-)